# How to extend a div to fill the whole page

Tags: html, css

I am building a page with two columns side-by-side that should fill the entire page. Both columns should both be 50% of the available width with no margin or padding on either side and take up 100% of the available height depending on the resolution.

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow: hidden;
}

body>* {
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

.login-column {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  background-color: #F4F6F9;
  margin: 0;
}

.news-column {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  background-color: #75BFF0;
  /* For browsers that do not support gradients */
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #75BFF0, #C9E7FF);
  /* Standard syntax (must be last) */
  margin: 0;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="login-column">
    <h1>Login</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="news-column">
    <h1>News</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Currently, the divs have no padding or margin on the top, left, and right; however, the background color only extends to the end of the text. I want the background to extend to the bottom of the page, without a scrollbar.

On a side note, I am using divs. Is this still recommended or should I be using the new, HTML5 things such as article, aside, .etc?

Comment: you can add height: 100vh to your divs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove floats, you can add height to your columns `100vh` but in your head section of the page should be `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow: hidden;
}

body>* {
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
.row {
  display: flex;
}
.login-column {
  flex: 0 0 50%;
  background-color: #F4F6F9;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
}

.news-column {
  flex: 0 0 50%;
  background-color: #75BFF0;
  /* For browsers that do not support gradients */
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #75BFF0, #C9E7FF);
  /* Standard syntax (must be last) */
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="login-column">
    <h1>Login</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="news-column">
    <h1>News</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

In order to get a DIV to fill the page in height you need to use this :

**CSS**

```
div {
height: 100vh;}
```

Also everything is explained in this post : 
[How to make a div 100% height of the browser window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1575141/how-to-make-a-div-100-height-of-the-browser-window)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply include height in div classes.
    .login-column {height: 100%;}
    .login-column {height: 100%;}

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to create a content div that contains the columns, i would try something like this.

```css
* {
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
    }
    
    body, html {
    height: 100%;
    }
    
    .columns-container {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: row;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
    }

    .login-column {
      display: flex
      background-color: #F4F6F9;
      margin: 0;
      width: 50%;
    }

   .news-column {
     display:flex;
     background-color: blue;
     margin: 0;
     width: 50%;
     height: 100%;
   }
```

```html
<div class="columns-container ">
    <div class="login-column">
        <h1>Login</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="news-column">
        <h1>News</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use `float`s and `position: absolute`, unless you absolutely know what you're doing. I suggest using a flex container to do what you want, and use max-height to make the two columns (sections) fill out the whole screen height. If you just use `height: 100vh`, the columns will stay at that height blocking things from overflowing.

Also note how I use class syntax to reuse CSS code.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.flex-container {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

section {
  min-height: 100vh;
  flex-basis: 50%;
  box-sizing: border-box; /* To let padding be part of the width */
  padding: 1rem;
}

section.left {
  background-color: #F4F6F9;
}

section.right {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #75BFF0, #C9E7FF);
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="flex-container">
    <section class="left column">
      Ladidaa
    </section>

    <section class="right column">
      Tralalaa
    </section>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding use of div, article and aside, actually they are used for to code semantic Html to get the best result for Search Engine Optimization and other bots related activity also good for other developers to understand code flow. Not answering your primary question as it already answered many times, let me know if you are not satisfied with other answers :)

Note: Using div is all fine in your case, don’t worry.